# Silverlight: Attaching events to items within an ItemsControl

Tags: silverlight, events, templates, itemscontrol

I'm trying to link up events to my radio buttons that are residing in an itemscontrol.

My template is below:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="RadioButtonsItemsControl" Height="auto" Width="auto" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding MapLayers}" >

                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                                <StackPanel Orientation="{TemplateBinding RadioButtonOrientation}" Margin="5"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <RadioButton Content="{Binding ID}" IsChecked="{Binding Visible, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    IsEnabled = "{Binding IsInScaleRange}"
                                    ToolTipService.ToolTip=""
                                    GroupName="BaseLayer"
                                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding ForeGroundBrush}" FontSize="11">

                                </RadioButton>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
```

In my .cs file for the custom control, I have a template part for the itemscontrol, and I attach the event

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        radioButtonsItemsControl = GetTemplateChild("RadioButtonsItemsControl") as ItemsControl;
        if (radioButtonsItemsControl != null) radioButtonsItemsControl.MouseLeftButtonDown += radioButtonsItemsControlMouseLeftButtonDown;
    }
```

radioButtonsItemsControl is not equal to null (and is not yet populated with the radio buttons at this stage), but the radioButtonsItemsControlMouseLeftButtonDown event should still register for later on when I click inside my items control.

```
 void radioButtonsItemsControlMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = e.OriginalSource as RadioButton;
        if (radioButton != null) radioButton.Checked += OnChecked;
    }
```

This never fires when I click in my itemscontrol though: radioButtonsItemsControlMouseLeftButtonDown.

Not sure I'm going about this the right way, so I'm open to alternative methods of attaching events to items inside ItemsControls.

Thanks, 
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to attach the event, I would do a partial class extension and give it a hashtable of commands that could be bound to.  In your case, the simplest way would be to define and event that is set after the list is bound.  For example, the property Visible, on the set would check to see if some event is defined, and if so, call it.  E.g.

Create an event to look at (OnRadioButtonChanged);
Attach to the event AFTER the list is loaded.
(detach the event once the  list is cleared for reload).
once the event exists, when the visibility is toggled, it will invoke the vent.  The code example is below:

```
public string Visibility
    {
        get
        {
            return __fVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            __fVisibility = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Visibility");
            if (!object.ReferenceEquals(OnVisibilityChanged, null))
                OnVisibilityChanged(null);
        }
    }
```

That to me is the cleaner and simpler solution.  :)